# How do you changing default padding bootstrap table cells?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap tables cells (td, th) have a default padding of 8px. What's a good way to change it to another value for all bootstrap tables?

Comment: Are you asking what the CSS would be, or where to apply it?

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming your are talking about the bootstrap pre-defined tables and not the grid system. If you want to change all the `padding` elements on one specific table you can do something like this in your html:

EDIT I switched the code because the other code was not working.

Try this CSS:

```
.mytable>tbody>tr>td, .mytable>tbody>tr>th, .mytable>tfoot>tr>td, .mytable>tfoot>tr>th, .mytable>thead>tr>td, .mytable>thead>tr>th {
    padding: 12px;
}
```

Add this class to your table

```
<table class="table mytable">
   table data here...
</table>
```

[Here is the JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qfnn6kgn/). There are a few other ways to do this like using the `!important` to over ride other CSS classes but I don't recommend it.